# Looping array using a counter

Tags: c

I'm working on this program that should output 10 prime numbers. So my problem is that I dont know how to tell the program to stop as soon as 10 prime  numbers have been stored in the array. I tried to do sizeof(primes)/siseof(int) == 10 , but its not working.
Help me please. Thanks in advance

```
 int ar[100],primes[10],j,n,i,var;

 printf("Enter a prime ,\n");

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
       scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
       if (IsPrime(ar[i])) {
        primes[i] = ar[i];
        if( sizeof(primes) / sizeof(int) == 10) break;

      } else {
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n", ar[i]);
      }
 }
 printf("\narray :\n");
```

Comment: Increment a counter, and test if it has reached 10.

Comment: I tried doing  if( sizeof(primes) / sizeof(int) == 10) break; but it doesnt work

Comment: `sizeof(primes) / sizeof(int)` is the size of the whole `primes` array, not the number that you've filled in so far.

Comment: You increment a counter with `counter++`. You test if it has reached 10 with `if (counter == 10)`.

Comment: `primes[i] = ar[i];` Clearly that's not right. Consider if `i` is 80. Also, `sizeof` is the size of the container, not its contents. It doesn't change when the contents change. So checking `sizeof` is wrong too.

Comment: Why is your program printing the contents of `ar[]` at the end, not the contents of `primes[]`?

Comment: In the if() you have to increment a counter and then you have to use it to exit the loop and to store the prime number:  cnt=cnt+1; primes[cnt]=ar[i] ... If n (as I think may be 100) when the variable i becoms 10 you'll have not memory to set primes[i]=ar[i].

Comment: Don't remove the original code from your question. It makes it impossible to understand the context of our answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to pitch something a bit more in line with your stated intention:

```
#define MAX_PRIMES 10
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int inval;
    int primes[MAX_PRIMES];
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter a prime number,\n");

    while (count < MAX_PRIMES)
    {
        scanf("%d", &inval);
        if (IsPrime(inval))
        {
            primes[count] = inval;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", inval);
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe elements of the array are:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PRIMES; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", primes[i]);
    }
}
```

`int ar[100]` was replaced with `int inval` because there doesn't seem to be any need to store the input values.

`for(i=0;i<n;i++)` replaced with `while (count < MAX_PRIMES)` because the previous version would stop at n whether 10 primes had been found or not.

`printf(" %d",ar[i])` was replaced with `printf(" %d", primes[i])` because the stated desired output is 10 primes, not the input array.

Could be a stupid tyop or two in there because I haven't run it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter variable. Use this as the index of the `primes` array, because otherwise you'll write outside the bounds of the array if the user enters more than 10 numbers to try.

```
int ar[100],primes[10],j,n,i,var;
int primesFound = 0;
printf("Enter a prime number,\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
        if (IsPrime(ar[i])) {
            primes[primesFound] = ar[i];
            primesFound++;
            if( primesFound == 10) break;

        } else {
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", ar[i]);
        }
    }
printf("\nThe elements of the array are:\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        printf(" %d",ar[i]);

    }
```

Comment: This works and allow me to store 10 primer numbers :), but then after it gets the 10 prime numbers the program crushes :(

Comment: You need to use `primes[primesFound]`, not `primes[i]`, because `i` can get higher than `9`.

Comment: Note that your program prints all the numbers that the user has entered, not just the prime ones, because you're printing `ar`, not `primes`.

Comment: Also, you'll print `n` entries of `ar`, even though the loop that fills in the array stops when you get to 10 primes. So the rest will be random garbage.

Comment: even if I change it to primes the program still cruches. Im uploading my entire code right now so you can run it my friend, and you will see that it crushes. Help me find what is causing the crushing please

Comment: I showed how to fix the crash. Did you change it from `primes[i]` to `primes[primesFound]`?

Comment: I did but it still crushes :( , can you run my code on your IDE please, I just uploaded my entire code

Comment: Your code has `primes[i] = ar[i];`. So you're lying, you didn't fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a counter

```
int ar[100],primes[10],j,n,i,var;

printf("Enter a prime number,\n");

int counter = 0; // here you declare a counter
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
    if (IsPrime(ar[i])) {
        counter++ // here you increase your counter
        primes[i] = ar[i];
        if (counter == 10) break;

    } else {
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n", ar[i]);
    }
}
printf("\nThe elements of the array are:\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

    printf(" %d",ar[i]);

}
```

Now, why the `if( sizeof(primes) / sizeof(int) == 10) break;` doesn't work? Because your `primes` is an array, which is declared statically and so its size is always a constant, which is equal to `10 * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: This works and allow me to store 10 primer numbers :), but then after it gets the 10 prime numbers the program crushes :(

Comment: The program crashes because you cannot use primes[i] when i becomes bigger then 9 ... Read my and Barmar comments in your question!

Comment: the counter for "primes" should be different from the one for "ar"